# How to estimate the max of a population using the normal distribution equation on a small sample

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference

I recently watched a documentary on Mathematics. In the show they managed to estimate the weight of the largest fish that the fisherman was likely to of ever caught in his career just by analysing one day's catch.

The presenter states he used the Normal Distribution Equation to figure this out. Could someone elaborate on how they managed to estimate the largest fish the fisherman ever caught by analysing just a few fish?

### Details

Here are the steps they used to estimate the weight of the largest fish likely to of ever been caught in the fisherman's career.

A fisherman caught some fish.
The fish were weighed.
Then, the average weight of the fish were calculated
Then, the Standard deviation was calculated
Then, the total amount of fish caught in the fisherman's career was calculated

- 40 years * 8 weeks during the year = 320
- 320 * 6 days of the week = 1920
- 1920 * 200 fish per day = 384,000 fish caught in his whole career.

Using these numbers he calculated the largest out of the 384,000 should be 1.3 KG, which turned out to be correct. How did he achieve this using Normal Distribution? The video is a little bare on the details being aimed at the layman.

[Link to video. 30:00](https://youtu.be/eOMZtBacarY?t=1734)

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the [standard score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score) table, $0.13\%=0.0013 \approx \frac 1{800}$ of the events are above mean+$3\sigma$ and most of those are close to mean+$3\sigma$.  Based on that, if he had caught $800$ fish, you would predict tat the largest was about mean+$3\sigma$.  They did the same thing based on the larger quantity of fish.  Out of $384,000$ fish you would expect the largest to be about $4.556 \sigma$ high.  This depends sensitively on the assumption that fish sizes are distributed normally, which is probably not true.

Comment: Could you explain it a more layman manner, at a similar level to the video? For example, what does the sentence `Based on that, if he had caught 800800 fish, you would predict tat the largest was about mean+3σ` actually mean?

Comment: Having a step-by-step example would be the best answer for comprehension. I.e. An answer that shows the steps from taking a sample of fish to measuring the maximum possible weight ever caught.

Comment: The [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) (please read the Wikipedia article) is a bump shaped distribution that depends on two parameters. The mean ($\mu $) is the top of the peak, and is the average value.  The standard deviation ($\sigma $) represents the width of the curve.  it turns out that 68% of the samples will be within $\pm 1 \sigma $ of the mean, 95% will be within $\pm 2 \sigma $ and 99.7% will be within $\pm 3 \sigma $ of the mean.

Comment: I didn't watch the video, but they weighed one day's catch and measured the mean and standard deviation from the day.  As you sample more and more fish, you expect to occasionally find one further and further from the mean.  This is where I got the expectation of $+3 \sigma $ if you look at $800$ fish and $+4.556 \sigma $ for $384,000$.  I'm sure that is what they did.

Comment: This all hinges on the assumption that the distribution of caught fish is normal, which is a terrible assumption.  The normal distribution is symmetric.  If the mean were 0.8 lb and the standard deviation were 0.1 lb, we would predict that 1 lb fish are as common as 0.6 lb fish and that 1.2 lb fish are as common as 0.4 lb fish.  One would expect that there would be more small fish than large fish.  It is also possible that a 0.6 fish has too small a mouth to be caught.